# Unable to access jarfile in appdata

Tags: java, windows, launch4j

I'm writing a Java program, and have a launch4j launcher. My JAR is stored under the users `%APPDATA%` folder, but when I try to use this in launch4j, I get this error:

[image]

Here is my `launch4j.xml` file (this is auto-generated by a Gradle plugin):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>%APPDATA%\Derby Pro\derby-pro.jar</jar>
  <outfile>DerbyPro.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>../../src/main/resources/com/neonorb/derbypro/assets/derby-pro-icon-favicon.ico</icon>
  <jre>
    <path>%APPDATA%\Derby Pro\jre</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>0.0.0.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>0.0.0</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>derby-pro</fileDescription>
    <copyright>unknown</copyright>
    <productVersion>0.0.0.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>Derby Pro</productName>
    <companyName>Neon Orb</companyName>
    <internalName>derby-pro</internalName>
    <originalFilename>DerbyPro.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by omitting the `<jar>` tag, and adding a `<opt>` tag containing `-jar "%APPDATA%\Derby Pro\derby-pro.jar"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the jar path location is relative to the execution path. %APPDATA% is treated as if it isn't a variable but a part of the whole path. If the jar file is in the same location as the launcher, you can just specify the filename.

Comment: This should be treated as a comment, but i don't have 50 reputation jet, i have to post an answer.

Comment: The JAR is not in the same directory as the launcher, it's in the APPDATA folder. The launcher is under program files.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the jar file needs to be in the APPDATA folder?

Comment: Because I need to automatically update it. I need admin privileges when it's in the program files.

Comment: Does changing the <jar> to just the filename and changing the <chdir> to "<chdir>%APPDATA%\Derby Pro\</chdir>" work?

Comment: That did not work, it tried to access `derby-pro.jar` in program files. It appears it didn't change the directory.

Comment: see my answer, I added a `<opt>` tag for the `-jar`.